# $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\bigg(\frac{2}{ \big( 2(k+1)+1\big)^3 }-\frac{2}{ \big(2(k+2)+1\big)^3}\bigg)}=2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n+1)^3}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I read in a book in a proof, and I found a step but I can no longer understand it

[image]

an idea please

Comment: It's not correct.  Did you mean $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\bigg(\frac{2}{ \big( 2({\color{red}2}k+1)+1\big)^3 }-\frac{2}{ \big(2({\color{red}2}k+2)+1\big)^3}\bigg)}=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n+1)^3}}$$

Comment: Your current LHS telescopes to $2/27$, but the RHS is $2-\pi^3/16$.